# How to get values from a form and send it to Java class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

First i have declare that i am new to javascript. I have created a form that gets Id, Name, Age & Dept. I want it to send to java class and i have to show back the data along with the other data in the data **Base** using DWR.

For this i already done coding for showing the table, below that i have my form.
After the form "Save" button calls the below function save(). Here, my form and function.

**The Form:**

```
Id:<input type="text" id="id"/><br>
Name:<input type="text" id="name"/><br>
Age:<input type="text" id="age"/><br>
Dept:<input type="text" id="dept"/><br>
<input id="Save" type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()"/>
```

**The function:**

```
function save(){
employee = new Object();
employee.id = dwr.util.getValue(iD);
employee.name = dwr.util.getValue(namE);
employee.age = dwr.util.getValue(agE);
employee.dept = dwr.util.getValue(depT);

dwr.engine.beginBatch();
Employee.aouEmployee(employee);  //   **Java method call to store data in DB**
fetch();//An another function which loads all the data in the table.
dwr.engine.endBatch();
}
```

But, i cant get proper output for the above function. I am also cant able to find the mistakes(due to no error msgs)

Any suggestions will be more appreciative

**Thanks**

**UPDATES ARE HIGHLIGHTED BY BOLD**

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "I have to show back the data along with the other data in the data". Do you mean that the Employee.aouEmployee() function returns data and you want to show it?

Comment: Sorry, the last data is Data'base', i missed it. The method returns void. fetch() ll call the showTable() method in java class?
I am still seeking for good answer.

Comment: So, the fetch function gets the data from the database? Maybe I'm stupid but I don't understand excactly where the problem is...

Comment: Btw, I don't think `dwr.util.getValue(iD);` is right. You should pass the parameter as a string, so: `dwr.util.getValue("id");` Unless `iD` is a variable that has been declared somewhere else.

Comment: No dude, Its correct syntax for that util. Check www.directwebremoting.com . Tell me how can i get 4 field values into single object. So that i can move further.

Comment: Yes dude, it is wrong syntax. Did you declare a variable named `iD`? I don't think you did, meaning `dwr.util.getValue(iD)` won't work because there is no variable named `iD`. It has nothing to do with DWR, it is how JavaScript works. If you don't believe me, see this example: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr-demo/simpletext/index.html - click on "How it works". You have to send a string to getValue(), and that string has to match the `id` attribute of a HTML element on the page.

Comment: @MaRaVaN: 4 values into single object: `employee = {id: null, name: null, age: null, dept: null }`. Then, a single `dwr.util.getValues(employee)` will fill them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install Firefox, if you haven't already
2. Install Firebug
3. Use Firebug to debug JS, as well as its Net panel to debug AJAX calls; use `console.log(string)` to get feedback
4. Profit.

By the way, for my curiosity: what's up with capitalising the last letter in a variable?

Comment: I am new to JS & i dont know will the values in the variable may overwrite the other values of other function variables. 
Will it recognize it as variable if i capitalize the last letter???

Comment: They can, but it's a very bad design if they're allowed to. All libraries worth their salt hide their variables so they are not visible (or overwritable) from the outside, using objects and closures. Thus, I would be very much surprised if DWR showed any variables besides `dwr`.

Comment: So, you know DWR. Ok, Anyway firebug rocks. Especially the break point. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nope, no idea about DWR, this post is the first time I ever heard of it. But I have a little bit of experience with JS. And yes, Firebug rocks.